# Understanding the proof of the existence of absolute integral closure

Tags: commutative-algebra, integral-extensions

I'm currently reading [this proof](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0DCR) in the stacks project showing the existence of absolutely integral closure. Here, we consider the set $I$ of all monic polynomials with coefficients in $A$ (so an element of $I$ is in $A[x]$). Then we construct a new ring $A[x_i;i \in I]/(P_i;i \in I)$, where $P_i$ is the corresponding polynomial in the variable $x_i$. The part I cannot understand is that the canoniacal map $A \to A[x_i;i \in I]/(P_i;i \in I)$ is an embedding. This is equivalent to saying that $A \cap (P_i;i \in I) = 0$, but how can we rigorously show that any linear combination of these polynomials does not magically cancel each other and only leave the constant term?

Comment: All $P_i$ are in the variable $x_i$ how could you get $0$? They are all algebraically independent

Comment: Since $(P_i;i \in I)$ is an ideal, their coefficients in linear combinations are also polynomials. For example, $x_1(x_2+1) - x_2(x_1) = x_1$, and my goal is showing that such linear combinations cannot be a nonzero constant. I'm not trying to prove that they become zero.

Comment: Yes but all the polynomial in this ideal don’t have a constant term… And I meant 1, not 0

Comment: Why do they don't have constant terms? $x_1-1$ is a monic polynomial and has a constant term.

Comment: Oh I misunderstood the definition of you $P_i$ sorry

Comment: Can you have both $x_i +1$ and $x_i$ in your generating set for your ideal ?

Comment: No. They should have different variables, so if $x_i$ is in the ideal, then the other should be $x_j+1$ where $i \neq j$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146866/discussion-between-jules-besson-and-luka).

Comment: Ok I get this tricky definition :)

Comment: Ok I see your very small error: Your I is not well defined, and, in fact you did not write the original definition correctly, $I$ is the set of all monics in $A [x]$, it can't have indeterminate indexed by $I$, so an element of $(P_i)$ is of the form $i(x_i)$ for some monic $I \in A[x]$ So your example does not work

Comment: I have a proof :)

Comment: Could you please upload your proof? I find it difficult to understand why the definition I wrote is incorrect. For each monic polynomial $i \in I \subseteq A[x]$, we are introducing a new indeterminate $x_i$. And $P_{i} = i(x_{i}) \in A[x_{i} ; i \in I]$, the polynomial corresponding to $i$ but using the variable $x_{i}$.

Comment: Yes I'm writing it

Comment: After further thinking your example is valid, sorry but your original definition was not, I have the idea but I'm stuck it's a matter of minutes I hope (I was too enthusiastic)

Comment: You're good :) Thanks a lot for thinking this problem with me!

Comment: If $A \cap (P_i : i \in I) \ne 0$, then there is a finite subset $I' \subseteq I$ with $A \cap (P_i : i \in I') \ne 0$. Then apply the following: for any ring $B$, any ideal $J \subseteq B$, and any nonconstant monic polynomial $f \in B[y]$, one has $B \cap (JB[y] + (f)) = J$